# how to display multi colum listitems in a textView

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a multi column listview that has been populated with json data. now on clicking a list item i need the datas of that particular list item to be displayed in the textView.

Answer (score 0):

In onItemClickListener of listview get the item from list which is set to the listview adapter using position variable of onItemClickListener method. Then set it to the textview.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
items = getListView();
items.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //Display content in Textview
        }
    });
```